# Download sample MRSID mg2, mg3 and mg4

Tags: mrsid

Are there any resources available where I can download mrsid data in mg2, mg3 and mg4 formats? I've been able to find mg2 with no problem but so far nothing for mg3 or mg4 formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the trial and create them from your own images?

http://www.lizardtech.com/products/lidar/

Answer (score 0):

The DSDK (free download at developer.lizardtech.com) supplies sample data: raster images (MG2 and MG3) and lidar data (MG4) -- but is currently missing any MG4/raster images, I think.

-mpg